# How to organize Android App code?

Tags: android, android-activity

First of all: I am rather new to Android App programming and I have a rather basic question:

Already with the sandbox app I am currently working on, the code in the Activity class get quite huge because all the callback methods / listeners (click listener, callbacks from GoogleApiClient) are in there (either by implementing the respective interface or by creating a private class). But I would rather put those into separate classes.

But the question that I ask myself is this: how would I then be able to access the class attributes of the activity class? Sure, I would then probably create setter/getter, but still I first need a reference to the Activity object. How would I get this?

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a really wide question, since the answer depends by your project and by your programming style. The first suggestion is: move what you can move in one or more fragment. All stuffs related to google play services can be nicely handled in a fragment for example. Listener and callback are UI related components, so they need a Context of an Activity to work, but you can split your UI (again) with Fragment and keep a piece of logic in a Fragment and another piece somewhere else. If you have some logic that runs in background, then you should consider using Service. I tend to have empty Activities, but this is not a rule.